# How to remove some data not needed on new row from mysql query with rollup

Tags: mysql, group-by, content-query-rollup

Hello I have a problem with the rollup mysql query. I want to get total of each column. I use mysql SUM() and ROLLUP to get the result. But on the new row that is added it copies the data of the last row. How can I remove those data. I provided an image on what I really needed to achieve.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT IFNULL(payments.id, "General Total"), payments.driver_id, payments.vehicle_specifications_id,payments.admins_id, payments.vehicle_id, payments.boundaries, payments.cashbond_payments, payments.loans, payments.penalties, SUM(payments.total_payments), a.first_name, a.mid_name, a.last_name, d2.date, d.first_name, d.mid_name, d.last_name, v.plate_number, v2.car_rate FROM payments INNER JOIN admins AS a ON payments.admins_id = a.id INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON payments.driver_id = d.id INNER JOIN dispatch AS d2 ON payments.dispatch_id =d2.id INNER JOIN vehicles AS v ON payments.vehicle_id = v.id INNER JOIN vehicle_specifications AS v2 ON payments.vehicle_specifications_id = v2.id GROUP BY payments.id WITH ROLLUP
```

[image]

Comment: The `rollup` works this way on non aggregate columns, you may use some other trick like get the `sum` in one query and then `union all` setting all not needed columns as `''` and sum the `payments.total_payments` without `group by`

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your answer. Do you have link for some example way to do it with union?

Comment: Just added one as answer, check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `union all`

```
SELECT 
payments.id, 
payments.driver_id, 
payments.vehicle_specifications_id,
payments.admins_id, 
payments.vehicle_id, 
payments.boundaries, 
payments.cashbond_payments, 
payments.loans, 
payments.penalties, 
SUM(payments.total_payments), 
a.first_name, 
a.mid_name, 
a.last_name, 
d2.date, 
d.first_name, 
d.mid_name, 
d.last_name, 
v.plate_number, 
v2.car_rate 
FROM payments 
INNER JOIN admins AS a ON payments.admins_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON payments.driver_id = d.id 
INNER JOIN dispatch AS d2 ON payments.dispatch_id =d2.id 
INNER JOIN vehicles AS v ON payments.vehicle_id = v.id 
INNER JOIN vehicle_specifications AS v2 ON payments.vehicle_specifications_id = v2.id 
GROUP BY payments.id 

union all
select 
'General Total' as id,
'' as driver_id, 
'' as vehicle_specifications_id,
'' as admins_id, 
'' as vehicle_id, 
'' as boundaries, 
'' as cashbond_payments, 
'' as loans, 
'' as penalties, 
SUM(payments.total_payments), 
'' as first_name, 
'' as mid_name, 
'' as last_name, 
'' as date, 
'' as first_name, 
'' as mid_name, 
'' as last_name, 
'' as plate_number, 
'' as car_rate 
FROM payments 
INNER JOIN admins AS a ON payments.admins_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON payments.driver_id = d.id 
INNER JOIN dispatch AS d2 ON payments.dispatch_id =d2.id 
INNER JOIN vehicles AS v ON payments.vehicle_id = v.id 
INNER JOIN vehicle_specifications AS v2 ON payments.vehicle_specifications_id = v2.id
```

Comment: Hello we have an error.. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''General Total' as id,
'' as driver_id, 
'' as vehicle_specifications_id,
'' ' at line 31

Comment: Wow your great man. Sorry about my thinking capacity. God bless you always.